# Rails support for HTML multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html-select, form-helpers

I have 2 models:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
end
```

I want to have an HTML multiple select in `_form.html.erb` that generates something like this:

```
<select id="game_category_id" name="game[category_id]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First Person Shooter</option>
  <option value="2">Role Playing Game</option>
</select>
```

When submitting the form to create a new `game` or edit a `game`, the categories selected should be saved accordingly. I typically use Rails' `collection_select` method for `select` fields. Can I use that for multiple selects as well?

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.order('name'), :id, :name, {include_blank: true}) %>
```

One issue is, of course, I don't have a `category_id` field in the `game` model. It's a collection of `categories`. I'm using the latest stable Rails (3.2.9 at the moment).

Comment: meaning that for Eg: game category can have option 1 and 2 value, when it submit or edit, the db will have 2 records which value 1 and 2?

Comment: @Nich - yes, I think. If you choose both categories for a game, the database will have 2 records in the `categories_games` join table.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847641/trying-to-use-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-has-and-belongs-to-many-but-the