# Rails: submit form with nested attributes throws 'couldn't find entity with id=xxx'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, nested-forms

I got the following model classes:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :actors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
  ...
end
```

movies/_form.html.haml view contains the nested form for actors:

```
...
= form_for @movie do |movie_form|
  = movie_form.fields_for :actors do |actor_form|
    = actor_form.text_field :id, "Id"
    = link_to_remove_fields "remove", actor_form
  = link_to_add_fields movie_form :actors
...
  = movie_form.submit 'Save'
```

`link_to_remove_fields` and `link_to_add_fields` are helper methods performing javascript calls, adding new fields for new actors or removing actors.

The controller:

```
   class MovieController < ApplicationController

     #POST form
     def create
       @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
       ...
     end

     #GET nearly empty form with one field for actor
     def new
       @movie = Movie.new
       1.times {@movie.actors.build}

       respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.json { render json: @movie }
       end
     end
   end
```

The problem:
  When 'Save' is pressed (with only one actor with id=718, for example) and the form is submitted, the `@movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])` line of the controller throws the following error:

> Couldn't find Actor with ID=718 for Movie with ID=

I'm sure that there is entity with id=718 in the Actor database.

Comment: Just to be sure, inspect the html of the form and ensure that its using the new path and not the edit path (just an idea)

Comment: how does your new action look like?

Comment: @Mattherick the 'new' method is added.

Comment: Are you trying to associate a movie with one or more existing actors or also create new actors as you go ?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung I'm trying to add existing actors to  new movie.

Comment: why do you build a new actor in your new action if you already have the actor in your db? I would recommend instead of building a new actor, create a select field in your form, where an user can select the actor - then it should work. And I don´t think, that you need accepts_nested_attributes_for in your case.

Comment: BTW, is it f.text_field :id, "Id"  or  actor_form.text_field :id, "Id"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing if you are trying to associating existing actors to a new movie is not to use `accepts_nested_attributes` at all.

One of the things you get with your actors associations is a `actor_ids`, which return the ids of the associated actors, or allows you to set the list of associated actors.

To submit an array via a rails form, the name of the input must end with [], for example if you have an input with name `movie[actor_ids][]` and value 1, then you'll get

```
{'movie' => {'actor_ids' => ['1']}}
```

in your controller. If you want to submit a second actor, just create another input with the same name `movie[actor_ids][]`. You could also use a select box with the `multiple` attribute set, but they can be a bit unfriendly for users especially when there are more than just a few options to pick from.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `has_and_belongs_to_many` (see [Trying to use accepts_nested_attributes_for and has_and_belongs_to_many but the join table is not being populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847641/trying-to-use-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-has-and-belongs-to-many-but-the) for example). You would probably be able to build something similar with a network of `has_many :x through: :y`s though.