# RoR Many to Many relationship and form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, collection-select

I'm stuck with this issue.
The RoR doc about this topic is really awful.
I don't understand how collection_select works.

I have two models : Skills and Projects.
A Project have many skills and a skill have many projects.

So here are my schemas :

```
create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "projects_skills", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "skill_id"
end

create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "mastering"
end
```

The Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

end
```

The Skill Model

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

end
```

And the collection_select

```
= form_for(instance_variable_get('@' + controller.controller_name.singularize)) do |f|

    .field

        = f.label :skills
        = collection_select(:skills, :id, Skill.all, :id, :name, {:multiple=>true})

    .actions

        = f.submit
```

The select appears well populated, but nothing is persisted in my database.

Maybe someone can see a mistake in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is fine as far as I can tell. You're saying the `select` box appears properly populated, but can you explain what you mean by *nothing is persisted in my database*? Do you mean when you submit the form, no skills are saved for that project?

Comment: I just realized, you forgot to put `f.` in front of the `collection_select`. Is that a typo in the question or how it appears in the form? If the latter, that could be your problem.

Comment: Yep Paul that's exactly my issue. It seems that both f.collection_select and collection_select are acceptable. And frankly, I don't know the difference...

Comment: As I said, the form is here, the select is well populated but when I submit, the skills selected are not saved for this project. I tried f.collection_select too.

Comment: According to the documentation, the first argument should be an object, not a collection. So try :skill instead of :skills. That will render <select name="skill[id]">

Comment: In which field are you expecting the values to be saved?

Comment: Can you post the `create` action controller code for this resource (I'm assuming its `Project`). You're right that both are acceptable, but the difference is in how the parameter map is built. If you do it the way I indicated, you will end up with the `skills` parameter inside of the overall `project` parameter list, which is usually desirable. That's why I'd like to see the `create` action because the problem could be in how you're constructing the object.

Comment: If you are expecting the values to be saved in `skill_id`,then you should give it like this `=f.collection_select(:skill_id, Skill.all, :id, :name, {:multiple=>true})`

Comment: Pavan, I get an undefined method `skill_id' when I do this. Paul, there is nothing special on the create method of Project. I thought the relations saving was automatic, this is not the case ?

Comment: Are you using it in `form_for`? Please post the full code.

Comment: Yep I'm using form_for, I edited to post it.

Comment: You will also need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in order to populate the join table. This post should have everything you need to get it working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847641/trying-to-use-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-has-and-belongs-to-many-but-the

Comment: `= form_for(instance_variable_get('@' + controller.controller_name.singularize)) do |f|`? a bit complicated.I expected something like this `= form_for(@skill) do |f|`.

Comment: It's the same, just a generic way to do it. I only have one form for all my models, and my fields are partials.